# Change Asp.Net RadListBoxItem visible state on filter

Tags: asp.net, events, visible, telerik-radlistbox

I have an ASPX form with a 'RadListBox' populated with 'RadListBoxItem' items.

I have a text box underneath it, which i want to use for filtering the items so that only the ones that match the text are displayed.

```
<telerik:RadListBox ID="m_members" runat="server" CheckBoxes="true" Width="500px" Height="350px"></telerik:RadListBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="m_memberFilter" runat="server" Width="492px" MaxLength="250" OnTextChanged="OnMemberFiltering" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

When the 'OnMemberFiltering' fires, I can loop through the items in the list as follows:

```
    foreach (RadListBoxItem item in m_members.Items)
    {
    }
```

But i cannot change the visible state for any of the items.

Scratching my head other this, what Am i doing wrong?  Any help would be greatly appreciated (not been using ASP for long).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it using Style["display"] for each item in the loop.